# Configuring Modules in Install Profile

Tags: 7, distributions, drush

I'm working on an install profile which brings in various modules and I was curious about the proper (or popular) convention for setting global variables  Right now I have two different ways of doing this:

1. In my settings.php file I set some variables directly in the $conf array:

   > $conf['var'] = 'setting';
2. In the install function of my profile I set some variables using variable_set:

   > variable_set('var', 'setting');

I recognize that the first one will permanently retain the setting until the php file is altered, while the other can be changed at any time.

Is there any popular opinion/convention on the method of setting these variables(in the context of using an install profile)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general using `hook_install` or `hook_enable` or a `hook_update` function in a module is prefered over hardcoding the value in `settings.php` of your drupal site.

Another option is to use the [Configuration](http://drupal.org/project/configuration) module or [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) to encapsulate your database configuration to `code` to be enabled on the drupal website.

Answer (score 2):

I am using settings.php for settings that are different in otherwise identical sites (staging, dev, production), so that I don't have to change the settings in the database when I sync the sites.

Some modules override database variables with settings in settings.php, like search api override.

Since settings.php is often the only site specific file, it is a handy place for making the rest of the site portable.

For an installation profile, I would set variables using variable_set.